# How to rotate a cube around it's edges in OpenGL using c++?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, transformation, glm-math

I want to write a function that expects 2 points and a rotation value.
With that information I want to rotate the cube on the edge between the two given points by the given rotation.

That's what I have tried:

```
void rotateAroundEdge(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2, float rot) {
    
    // Calculate the axis of rotation
    float axis_x = y2 - y1;
    float axis_y = z2 - z1;
    float axis_z = x2 - x1;

    // Normalize the axis of rotation
    float length = sqrtf(axis_x * axis_x + axis_y * axis_y + axis_z * axis_z);
    axis_x /= length;
    axis_y /= length;
    axis_z /= length;
    
    // Translate the cube so that the edge is at the origin
    Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(x1, y1, z1));

    // Rotate the cube around the edge
    Model = glm::rotate(Model, rot, glm::vec3(axis_x, axis_y, axis_z));
    

    // Translate the cube back to its original position
    Model = glm::translate(Model, glm::vec3(-x1, -y1, -z1));
    
}
```

but somehow the rotation point is not on the edges.

Comment: try swapping around the two translate calls?